# How to pass ForEach parameters to a SwiftUI views?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I am try to show three pages in SwiftUI, let's name them as:

`TopGroup.swift`  (first level pages, here includes some main group of books)
`SubGroup.swift`  (second level pages, here include some sub group of books)
`Detail.swift`    (third level pages, here show the detail info of every book)

I linked the `SubGroup.swift` and `Detail.swift` pages, but failed to link `TopGroup.swift` to `SubGroup.swift`. for I don't know how to pass argument or parameter by subscript or other ways.

the data model defined like this:

```
struct Top: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let group: [Group]
    subscript(_ groupIndex: Int) -> Group {
        return group[groupIndex]
    }
}

struct Group: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()  
    let name: String 
    let books: [Book]  // which define the detail info of every book
}
```

I wrote the code of `RootGroup.swift` like this:

```
struct TopGroup: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                // here show top group name
                ForEach(top) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        SubGroup()  // here link to subgroup
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code of `SubGroup.swift` like this:

```
struct SubGroup: View {    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
            
            // here should be subgroup like group[0], group[1], group[2]...
                ForEach(group[0]) { item in
                    Section(header: Text("Books Category of \(item.name)")) {
                        
                        // here link to detail book info
                        ForEach(item.books) { bookItem in
                            NavigationLink {
                                Detail(book: bookItem)
                            } label: {
                                BookRow(book: bookItem)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(top[0].name, displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am confused about:

1. how to pass the parameter from `TopGroup.swift` to `SubGroup.swift`, so every item in the `top` can link to the right page.
2. the `SubGroup.swift` will show multi views of instance of group Array's content such as `group[0]`, `group[1]`, `group[2]`..., I do not like to create multi like `SubGroup0.swift`, `SubGroup1.swift`, `SubGroup3.swift`... which link to `TopGroup.swift`.

I have tried several days but can't solve it. Thanks a lot~~

The diagram show as attached:
[image]

Comment: Don't you just need to pass `item` to `SubGroup`?

Comment: Pass in the item as an argument. Also get rid of that inner NavigstionView most apps only need one tab views and sheets are exceptions. Try watching Demystify SwiftUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a constant in SubGroup taking your group array or the whole Top object:

```
let item: Top
```

Pass the object to the SubGroup view:

```
SubGroup(item: item)
```

Basically since views in SwiftUI are just structures you can define constants (or variables) and an initializer will be automatically generated for you.

Comment: but, how to show the Array of `group[group[0], group[1], group[2]...]` in `SubGroup` ? I would not to create multi SubGroup.swift which link to `TopGroup.swift`.

Comment: @chang356 just replace `group[0]` in `SubGroup` with `item.group` if you are following my suggestion. `{ top1: { group1: { book1, book2 }, group2: { book3, book4 } } }`. (sorry no new lines in comments)

Comment: @chang356 Oh and `top[0].name` to `item.name`. Please let me know if I am not getting what you are trying to achieve. At the moment from what I can understand you want to show each `Top`'s name > on tap > show each `Group`'s name and each `Book` in that subgroup under it

Comment: Thanks your help, I update the code and it seems work, but the preview of `SubGroup_Previews` remind error when I wrote with `static var previews: some View { SubGroup(item: Top)} `, it previous was `static var previews: some View { SubGroup()} ` , Could you tell me what's wrong with it ? Thank you~~

Comment: @chang356 You need to initialize SubGroup correctly with a populated Top object example: `SubGroup(item: Top(name: "Item 1", group: [Group(name: "Group 1", books: [Book(name: "Book 1", author: "Author 1", description: "Description", imageName: "{no idea}")])]))`. The preview only serves a debugging purpose to visualize your SwiftUI code in the canvas.

Comment: Woh, it work! Thanks a lot! previous I hesitate myself about the syntax so long and don't write it, but it works after I follow your advice. How nice from you~~